# Unique Factorization

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

I need help with the following:

(i) Show that in R{x}, no polynomial of odd degree >1 is irreducible.

The question is a bit confusing because I interpret it as Show that in R{x}, all polynomials of odd degree >1 are reducible.

For example:

$$x^5 + x^4 + 1$$ should be reducible but I'm not sure if it is, how do I know if it is reducible or not?

(ii) Show that if f(x) in R{x} has a multiple factor, then its derivative f'(x) is not relatively prime to f(x).

Comment: It's reducible over $\mathbb R$, it's not reducible over $\mathbb Z$. Ask yourself why $x^3-2$ is reducible over $\mathbb R$, first. Then $x^5-2$, etc.

Comment: But how do we know it's reducible? That is the question.

Comment: It has a root, by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: I see, the section of our book did not mention the IVT so I assumed we couldn't use it.

Comment: are you familiar with something like every complex polynomial has a complex root... I doubt you are not :O

Comment: You doubt I am not? Double Negative, so I am familiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (ii), write $f=g^2h$ with $g$ not constant. Then $f'= 2gg'h+g^2h'$. Hence $g$ divides both $f$ and $f'$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Any odd degree polynomial has a root, which implicitly gives a factorization over $\mathbb R$.